# Dynamically create a summary based on a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have searched a lot but I didn't find anything about it.

The backend prints a whole document in a page, and I need to create a summary based on the headings (from h2 to h6), like Microsoft Office Word.

I would create a nested ordered list, like this, but with more levels:

```
1. Lorem Ipsum
    1.1 Lorem ipsum
    1.2 Lorem ipsum
2. Lorem ipsum
```

Sorry, I don't have a code because it's a very specific thing and I don't know how to start :P
You can send me a code or an idea.

Sorry for any english mistake.

Edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/9x64gjam/1/
For a better explanation, the javascript should render an ordered list like in the fiddle, using the div.text.

Comment: what kind of document is it? HTML? PDF?

Comment: Could you give us a sample of that HTML, and what precise output you want, based on that HTML? What should trigger the creation of an `<ol>`, or a child `<li>`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9x64gjam/

The html above with the headings should print that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go. Go ahead and try it below or [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x64gjam/3/) (http://jsfiddle.net/9x64gjam/3/). Scroll down to the "Table of Contents".

What we do is iterate over all headers (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) and create a stack where we then add (`push`) elements if we meet a header of the next level (e.g. if we are on the level `h2` and meet an `h3`). Whereas when we reach a header of a lower level, we remove elements  (`pop`) from the stack until we reach the top level (e.g. if we are on the level `h5` and the next is `h2`, we will `pop` four elements: `h5`,`h4`,`h3` and `h2`).

Please note that I updated you HTML just a bit and created a `div#content` around the area where you have the headers.

```js
$(function () {
        "use strict";

        var $content = $('#content'), // where we should look for headers.
            toc = document.createElement('ol'), // the main "table of contents" element.
            listStack = [];

        // Find all headers first.
        $content.children('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function (index, el) {
            var currentHeader = el,
                currentLevel = Number(currentHeader.tagName.substr(1)), // get the level of this header.

                lastListItem = listStack[listStack.length - 1],
                lastListItemLevel = lastListItem ? lastListItem.level : 0, // get the level of the previous header.
                ol, li;

            // Ensure a new header is on a higher level.
            // pop while we do not reach the first closest parent header (of the higher level).
            while (currentLevel <= lastListItemLevel) {                     listStack.pop();
                lastListItem = listStack[listStack.length - 1];
                lastListItemLevel = lastListItem ? lastListItem.level : 0;
            }

            // The content of the current header itself.
            li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = currentHeader.innerHTML;

            // New placeholder for the (possible) future children
            ol = document.createElement('ol');

            li.appendChild(ol);

            if (lastListItem) {
                // Append the new child to the current placeholder.
                lastListItem.ol.appendChild(li);
            } else {
                // If there were no last item, add the new child on the top level.
                toc.appendChild(li);
            }

            // Save a reference to the new parent on this level.
            listStack.push({
                level: currentLevel,
                ol: ol
            });
        });

        document.body.appendChild(toc);
    });
```

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item
}
li {
    display: block
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    
<h2>Lorem ipsum title</h2>

    <p>random text</p>
    
<h3>Lorem ipsum subtitle</h3>

    <p>random text</p>
    
<h3>Lorem ipsum subtitle</h3>

    
<h4>Lorem ipsum subsubtitle</h4>

    
<h2>Lorem upsum title</h2>

</div>


<h1>Table of Contents</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Use the [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) jquery for this, for example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>find demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ol type="1">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
</ol>

<script>
  $("h1").replaceWith( "<li>" + $("h1").text() + "</li>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you didn't get it, I need to create a summary based on the heading tags, and then add to a nested ordered list, in the right order, the h2 will be the child of h1, the h3 will be a child of h2.
I can't hide the text.

Comment: I've just update my answer, you could use some jquery functions like replaceWith or append to modify the output